# gpg-agent in gpg2

Tags: gnupg, encryption-symmetric

I'm attempting to futureproof some custom software that utilizes GPG (currently v 1.4.10) to perform **symmetric** encryption/decryption processes. My current encryption command looks like this:

```
gpg --batch --no-tty --no-use-agent --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase "foobar" /path/to/file_to_be_encrypted
```

Without the `--no-use-agent` option, I get the infamous error message

> *gpg-agent is not available in this session*

I'm concerned about a move to gpg2 because, [according to the documentation](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/GPG-Configuration-Options.html), the gpg-agent is always required, and `--no-use-agent` is simply a dummy option. My gpg calls occur in the background via a daemon process, so this is very much a no-agent scenario (plus the fact that it's symmetric, and I have no need of the agent at all).

Documentation at this level of detail is sparse, so I'm looking for user experience. Does gpg2 incorporate the agent more tightly, so that I don't have to worry about its availability?

Comment: You should accept sinharaj's answer. He gave you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The way you invoke `gpg2`, it might fail if the output file `path/to/file_to_be_encrypted.gpg` already exists. If you want the file to be overwritten, you should provide the `--yes` option:

   ```
   gpg2 --batch --yes --no-tty --no-use-agent --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase "foobar" /path/to/file_to_be_encrypted
   ```
2. When you are using symmetric encryption (like you do), the *passphrase constraints* (even if set to *enforced* by `gpg-agent`) will not be applied at all—it will just work.

   Say the `gpg-agent` was run like this (and let the `mypasswords` file even contain the forbidden pattern that exactly matches your password):

   ```
   eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --enforce-passphrase-constraints --min-passphrase-len 8 --min-passphrase-nonalpha 4 --check-passphrase-pattern mypasswords)
   ```

   Then your command would still succeed.

   In short: `gpg-agent` will not make it fail <s>(unless it crashes gpg for some reason—like wrong configuration or missing executable, which you cannot account for)</s>.

   **EDIT**: I've just checked and in symmetric mode gpg2 will **work** even if gpg-agent is wrongly configured **or** if the gpg-agent executable is missing.

   This is not related, but just in case: I also verified what happens when you try to change the password of your private key while gpg-agent is missing **or** is wrongly configured: gpg2 will report a warning, will not even ask for the new passphrase, and continue working.

Sources:

- [`gpg-agent` configuration manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#option%20--options)
- [`gpg` documentation](http://www.gnupg.org/docs.html)

Comment: how about decrypt, is there any way work without gpg-agent?

Comment: I would bet that this depends on whether you're using symmetric encryption or not. If not, this probably won't work since the gpg-agent manages private keys.